# JQuery — удаление класса при изменении разрешения

Tags: jquery, css

Есть обычное меню, кнопка(гамбургер) которого появляется, при разрешении меньше `768рх`. При нажатии выплывает само меню, но если увеличить разрешении это меню не исчезает. Конечно можно сделать через медиа-запрос `display:none`, но тогда при уменьшении разрешения меньше `768рх` меню появляется в развернутом виде и не спрятано за кнопку.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Menu button on click event
    $('.mobile-nav-button').on('click', function() {
        // Toggles a class on the menu button to transform the burger menu into a cross
        $( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(1)" )
            .toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--1");
        $( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(2)" )
            .toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--2");
        $( ".mobile-nav-button .mobile-nav-button__line:nth-of-type(3)" )
            .toggleClass( "mobile-nav-button__line--3");
        // Toggles a class that slides the menu into view on the screen
        $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobile-menu--open');

        return false;
        // if(($(window).width()) > 767){
        //  $('.mobile-menu').removeClass('mobile-menu--open');
        // };
 });
```

Comment: Так или иначе, вам нужно решать это через `@media`. Если у вас что-либо ломается при его использовании - это признак того, что вам нужно довести и остальную верстку до ума, используя все тот же `@media`, но никак не считать этот путь неверным.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Что не работает? Что хочешь сделать этим кодом? Какой вопрос перед нами ставишь? Если ты спрашиваешь про событие, которое срабатывает при изменении размера, то это `.resize`. В твоём коде это будет выглядеть так: `$(window).resize(function(){if($(window).width() > 767) $('.mobile-menu').removeClass('mobile-menu--open')})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы почти сами справились!

Воспользуйтесь [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) для подписки на событие, возникающее при изменении размеров окна:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if($(window).width() >= 768){
        $('.mobile-menu').removeClass('mobile-menu--open');
    };
}
```

Она гласит, что если при изменении размера окна его размер станет `>= 768`, то удалится класс `.mobile-menu--open`.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу поблагодарить **MihailPw** за решение и чуть дополнить его ответ. Не хватает закрывающей скобки для resize в самом конце:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  if($(window).width() >= 768){
    $('.mobile-menu').removeClass('mobile-menu--open');
  };
})
```

Comment: Из-за небольшой опечатки не стоит давать ответ, достаточно комментария.

Comment: Так и собирался сделать, но, увы, не было возможности из-за отсутствия рейтинга ‍♂️